# Nodal color information are lost for collada 3D files (*.dae)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a collada  (.dae) 3D file with nodal colour for contouring. But these information are lost while uploading to autodesk viewer api. I have attached the file for reference.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApS9nIpyJIuQbJulgP5rcm1b-ic

Is there any other way to show contour in viewer api ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately, the DAE, Obj, FBX pipelines only translation geometry. Material & Textures won't get through. We are working on a process to handle this as well as supporting glTF. The is no solution to workaround this limitation at this time.